# How to pass init parameters to Predictor class via seldon-core-microservice?

Tags: seldon, seldon-core

Is it possible to pass init parameters to Predictor class through seldon-core-microservice?

There is a `--parameters` arg available for `seldon-core-microservice` but there is no clear documentation on the format in which parameters should be passed.

The below link discuss same issue:

- https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/issues/2250

They point to following github code links:

- https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/blob/master/python/seldon_core/microservice.py#L222-L224
- https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/blob/master/python/seldon_core/microservice.py#L68-L114

Unittest are also not created for good examples:

- https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/blob/2f14dbdce57583995d818cc25772adf1c475c4de/python/tests/test_microservice.py#LL211C1-L211C1

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the format that is working.

`$ seldon-core-microservice InferenceModel --service-type MODEL --debug --parameters '[{"name":"model_path", "value":"value", "type": "STRING"}]'`

Value for type should be one of these: `INT, FLOAT, DOUBLE, STRING, BOOL`
reference:

https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/blob/2f14dbdce57583995d818cc25772adf1c475c4de/python/seldon_core/microservice.py#LL109C4-L109C4